# is it possible to copyObject from one cloud object storage instance to another. The buckets are in different regions

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

I would like to use the node sdk to implement a backup and restore mechanism between 2 instances of Cloud Object Storage. I have added a service ID to the instances and added a permissions for the service id to access the buckets present in the instance i want to write to. The buckets will be in different regions. I have tried a variety of endpoints both legacy and non-legacy private and public to achieve this but i usually get Access Denied.

Is what I am trying to do possible with the sdk? if so can someone point me in the right direction?

```
var config = {
 "apiKeyId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "endpoint": "s3.eu-gb.objectstorage.softlayer.net",
 "iam_apikey_description": "Auto generated apikey during resource-key operation for Instance - crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/xxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxx::",
 "iam_apikey_name": "auto-generated-apikey-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "iam_role_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam::::serviceRole:Writer",
 "iam_serviceid_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam-identity::a/0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx::serviceid:ServiceIdxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "serviceInstanceId": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx::",
"ibmAuthEndpoint": "iam.cloud.ibm.com/oidc/token"
```

}

Comment: Are you logging in to the two instances?

Comment: Honestly not sure how to answer that. I have a service credential which i got from IAM and attached to a instance1. I then grant this serviceId access to the buckets in the second service. Then i take that service id and try to use it to access the COS using the sdk -
 `var AWS = require('ibm-cos-sdk');
 //set the config to above
var cos = new AWS.S3(config);`

Comment: You need to log in to cos1 to read, log in to cos2 to write

Comment: Does that mean that we need to copy all data down from COS and upload it again? Is the copyObject function within the JavaScript SDK only useful within the same instance?

Comment: my understanding is that it is within an instance - if you work with two independent services, you kind of juggle between them

Comment: Thanks, sounds like we can't do what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the breakdown here is a bit confusing due to some unintuitive terminology.

A **service instance** is a collection of buckets. The primary reason for having multiple instances of COS is to have more granularity in your billing, as you'll get a separate line item for each instance. The term is a bit misleading, however, because COS is a true multi-tenant system - you aren't actually provisioning an *instance* of COS, you're provisioning a sort of sub-account within the existing system.

A **bucket** is used to segment your data into different storage locations or storage classes. Other behavior, like CORS, archiving, or retention, acts on the bucket level as well.  You don't want to segment something that you expect to scale (like customer data) across separate buckets, as there's a limit of ~1k buckets in an instance. IBM Cloud IAM treats buckets as 'resources' and are subject to IAM policies.

Instead, data that doesn't need to be segregated by location or class, and that you expect to be subject to the same CORS, lifecycle, retention, or IAM policies can be separated by **prefix**.  This means a bunch of similar objects share a path, like `foo/bar` and `foo/bas` have the same *prefix* `foo/`.  This helps with listing and organization but doesn't provide granular access control or any other sort of policy-esque functionality.

Now, to your question, the answer is both yes and no.  If the buckets are in the same *instance* then no problem.  Bucket names are unique, so as long as there isn't any secondary managed encryption (eg Key Protect) there's no problem copying across buckets, even if they span regions.  Keep in mind, however, that large objects will take time to copy, and COS's strong consistency might lead to situations where the operation may not return a response until it's completed.  Copying across instances is not currently supported.

Answer (score 2):

This should work as long as you are able to properly grant the requesting user access to be able to read the source of the put-copy, so long as you are not using KeyProtect based keys.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I am not using key  protect and have tried reading and writing to buckets in different regions in the same instance. I'm not clear on how i can connect to an instance with a bucket in eu-de and write to an instance in us-south. to interact with them i can use the same credential but i have to change the endpoints between calls. if i don't change the endpoint i get a NoSuchBucket error, when trying to list objects, if trying to use the copyObject method, i can read from bucket 1, but when i try to write to bucket 2 i get a NoSuchKey error, the object shouldn't exist